# Issue with loading third party library in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

Issue with loading third party library which is dependence on another third party library. In my case, i'm using bootstrap(v3.3.7) which is required JQuery. I included these libraries as per angular suggested way and successfully compile the application, if run it in browser i got a console error.

**Versions**

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
"@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.33",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"jquery": "3.3.1",
"malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin": "3.1.5",
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26" }
```

**Sample code and console error**

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from 
'@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   title = 'app'; 

   constructor(private element: ElementRef){ }
   ngOnInit() {
      $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
   }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
"options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/ang6",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          { "input": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" },
          { "input": "src/styles.css" }
        ],
        "scripts": [
          { "input": "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" },
          { "input": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" }
        ]
      },
```

**console error**

[error_message_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Ppr.jpg)

Is angular 6 changed the way of load/include the third party library files? Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: looks like the screenshot attachment got missed. Also paste the content rather than images as its easier to view and respond, and quick to copy and check.

Comment: @NitinSingh i have edited my question please check it now.